# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: string Access>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I want to return list of string in function :

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetAccessLevels(Guid roleId)
{
    return await AccessLevels.Where(x => x.RoleId == roleId).Select(x=>new {x.Access }).ToListAsync();
}
```

But it show me this error :

> Cannot implicitly convert type `'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: string Access>>'` to `'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>'`. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

This is my model :

```
public Guid RoleId { get; set; }
public string Access { get ; set; }
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change this:

```
Select(x => new { x.Access })
```

To This:

```
Select(x => x.Access)
```

The reason is, `new` makes your query to return an `IEnumerable` of [`Anonymous types`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types), while you need an `IEnumerable` of `Strings`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to do as follow:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetAccessLevels(Guid roleId)
{
    return await AccessLevels.Where(x => x.RoleId == roleId).Select(x=> x.Access).ToListAsync();
}
```

No need to create an anonymous object in the `Select`.